# WPF TabControl no selected Item on start

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am using a WPF tabcontrol to display items which are bound from a viewmodel.

By default on start the first item of  the list is selected but I want no item to be selected on start. I can set the SelectedItem in the OnSelectionChanged event to null then no item is selected on start but then it is no longer possible to manually select a item.

```
public partial class ProjectScopeMain : Window
{
  private bool firstStart = true;

  public ProjectScopeMain()
  {
    this.Initialized += this.ProjectScopeMain_Initialized;
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void ProjectScopeMain_Initialized(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    this.TabControlSettings.SelectionChanged += TabControlSettingsOnSelectionChanged;
  }

  private void TabControlSettingsOnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this.TabControlSettings.SelectedItem = null;
  }

  private void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

My XAML Code. SelectedIndex=-1 does not work

```
        <customControls:TabControl x:Uid="tabControlSettings" x:Name="TabControlSettings" 
                                   prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.ProjectScopeTabsRegion}" 
                                   TabStripPlacement="Left" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}" 

                                   ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemVerticalProjectScopeStyle}" SelectedIndex="-1"/>
```

Comment: i dont see any mvvm - where are your bindings?

Comment: Set the `SelectedIndex` to -1 in your xaml

Comment: I don't believe the TabControl allows you to have no tab selected. You may need to implement a way of hiding the content until a user clicks on a tab

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe the tab control lets you have nothing selected. An easy work around for this is to create an empty tab with a collapsed visibility, and navigate to it when you would otherwise wish to clear your tab control. This will result in a tab's content being shown (which in this case is empty) and no header being present.

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl" SelectedIndex="0">
    <TabItem Header="" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <!--There's nothing here-->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Item 1">
        <TextBlock Text="Some item 1" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Item 2">
        <TextBlock Text="Some item 2" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

You could 'clear' it with:

```
MyTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Since you wish to bind the child items, I would imagine you will need to combine the children in a resource first.

Answer (score 2):

You can deselect any `TabItem` by setting its [`IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected) property to `false`. The content of `TabControl` will be blank once none of its `TabItem`s are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the `TabControl` then set `SelectedItem` to null:

```xml
<TabControl Loaded="TabControl_OnLoaded">
    <TabItem Header="page 1" Content="page 1" />
    <TabItem Header="page 2" Content="page 2" />
</TabControl>
```

```cs
private void TabControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

It will work even if you bind `SelectedItem` to a property in your ViewModel, but there will be a moment after loading the page that you'll get a non-null value there, and after that null, but from what I've seen it didn't cause any weird flickering or anything so it's probably fine.

Tested on .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score -1):

You can select nothing by setting SelectedTab property nullptr.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab?view=net-5.0

> A TabPage that represents the selected tab page. If no tab page is selected, the value is null.

Comment: The question is for WPF, not winforms.